# Deserialize JSON having combined keys "(String, Integer, String)" back to multimap object

Tags: json, guava, multimap

I've created a json file from a multimap guava object using ObjectMapper. And now i want to deserialize the json file to a java object. The json contains combined key (String, Integer, String). 
I don't want to Use Map>>.

```java
Multimap<Triple<String, Integer, String>, Integer> eventConf = HashMultimap.create();

eventConf.put(Triple.of("NOTIFICATION", EventType.EVENT_TYPE_COMMENT_VIDEO.getEventType() ,"GRP_USER"), 0);
         eventConf.put(Triple.of("NOTIFICATION", EventType.EVENT_TYPE_COMMENT_VIDEO.getEventType() ,"GRP_USER_FOLLOWERS"), 0);
         eventConf.put(Triple.of("NOTIFICATION", EventType.EVENT_TYPE_COMMENT_VIDEO.getEventType() ,"GRP_PROFILE"), 1);
         eventConf.put(Triple.of("NOTIFICATION", EventType.EVENT_TYPE_COMMENT_VIDEO.getEventType() ,"GRP_PROFILE_FOLLOWERS"), 0);

try {
             mapper.writeValue(new File("EventProcessorConfig.json"), eventConf.asMap());
         } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

What i'm getting as a json is this

```
{
 "(NOTIFICATION,52,GRP_PROFILE_FOLLOWERS)":[  
      0
   ],
   "(NOTIFICATION,52,GRP_PROFILE)":[  
      0
   ],
   "(NEWSFEED,52,GRP_USER)":[  
      1
   ],

   "(NEWSFEED,52,GRP_USER_FOLLOWERS)":[  
      1
   ]
}
```

How to deserialize this json to a multimap object?